# Python 2 re.sub issue

Tags: python, regex, string, python-2.7, python-3.4

I got this a function that replaces sub-string matches with the match surrounded with HTML tags. This function will consume string in English and Greek mostly.

The function:

```
def highlight_text(st, kwlist, start_tag=None, end_tag=None):
    if start_tag is None:
        start_tag = '<span class="nom">'

    if end_tag is None:
        end_tag = '</span>'

    for kw in kwlist:
        st = re.sub(r'\b' + kw + r'\b', '{}{}{}'.format(start_tag, kw, end_tag), st)
    return st
```

The testing string is in Greek except the first sub-string [Korais]: st=*"Korais Ο Αδαμάντιος Κοραής (Σμύρνη, 27 Απριλίου 1748 – Παρίσι, 6 Απριλίου 1833), ήταν Έλληνας φιλόλογος με βαθιά γνώση του ελληνικού πολιτισμού. Ο Κοραής είναι ένας από τους σημαντικότερους εκπροσώπους του νεοελληνικού διαφωτισμού και μνημονεύεται, ανάμεσα σε άλλα, ως πρωτοπόρος στην έκδοση έργων αρχαίας ελληνικής γραμματείας, αλλά και για τις γλωσσικές του απόψεις στην υποστήριξη της καθαρεύουσας, σε μια μετριοπαθή όμως μορφή της με σκοπό την εκκαθάριση των πλείστων ξένων λέξεων που υπήρχαν στη γλώσσα του λαού."*

The test code:

```
kwlist = ['ελληνικού', 'Σμύρνη', 'Αδαμάντιος', 'Korais']
d = highlight_text(st, kwlist, start_tag=None, end_tag=None)
print(d)
```

When I'm running the code [st is the above string] only sub-strings in English get tagged. Greek substr are ignored. Notice that I run the above block on Python 2.7. When I use Python 3.4 all sub-string get replaced.
Another issue is that when I'm running the above function withing Flask application, it throws me an error: unexpected end of regular expression.

How should I tackle the above issue without using external library if possible?
I'm pulling my hairs off my head two days now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python 2.7, you need to explicitly convert text to Unicode. See the fixed snippet below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
def highlight_text(st, kwlist, start_tag=None, end_tag=None):
    if start_tag is None:
        start_tag = '<span class="nom">'

    if end_tag is None:
        end_tag = '</span>'

    for kw in kwlist:
        st = re.sub(ur'\b' + kw.decode('utf8') + ur'\b', 
           u'{}{}{}'.format(start_tag.decode('utf8'), kw.decode('utf8'), end_tag.decode('utf8')),
           st.decode('utf8'), 0, re.U).encode("utf8")
    return st

st="Korais Ο Αδαμάντιος Κοραής (Σμύρνη, 27 Απριλίου 1748 – Παρίσι, 6 Απριλίου 1833), ήταν Έλληνας φιλόλογος με βαθιά γνώση του ελληνικού πολιτισμού. Ο Κοραής είναι ένας από τους σημαντικότερους εκπροσώπους του νεοελληνικού διαφωτισμού και μνημονεύεται, ανάμεσα σε άλλα, ως πρωτοπόρος στην έκδοση έργων αρχαίας ελληνικής γραμματείας, αλλά και για τις γλωσσικές του απόψεις στην υποστήριξη της καθαρεύουσας, σε μια μετριοπαθή όμως μορφή της με σκοπό την εκκαθάριση των πλείστων ξένων λέξεων που υπήρχαν στη γλώσσα του λαού."
kwlist = ['ελληνικού', 'Σμύρνη', 'Αδαμάντιος', 'Korais']
d = highlight_text(st, kwlist, start_tag=None, end_tag=None)
print(d)
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/KkqMRv)

Note that all literals are declared with `u` prefix and all variables are `decode`ed and the `re.sub` result is `encode`d back to UTF8.

Comment: While this works if I run it from a separate script, it's now working inside my flask application. st is coming from database using flask-sqlalchemy. I have already set the connection string to utf8 to no avail. It throes me an error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u03bd' in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: You do not need to set the connection string to UTF8, you will be able to decode it later inside the Python script. Just get the string as usual. That warning also means you forgot to convert some string at some place to UTF8 (during processing). Did you use `re.U` with `re.sub`?

Comment: Also, check this [PEP 0263 -- Defining Python Source Code Encodings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) resource.

Comment: Yes I'm using re.U with re.sub. The error comes from `st.decode('utf8'), 0, re.U).encode("utf8")`

Comment: On the top of the script I placed `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: That line sets the encoding for the current file. The problem is that you get the `st` string as a Unicode literal. Try getting it with normal encoding.

Comment: Where should I do this?

Comment: I do not know flask-sqlalchemy. You can see that the Python code I posted works in the Python IDE. The string should be usual byte array with your usual encoding.

Answer (score 0):

> English get tagged. Greek substr are ignored.

Where does your `st` come from? Please notice that in Python 2.x `'μορφή' != u'μορφή'` Maybe you are comparing `str` with `unicode`.

Suggestions: Use `unicode` everywhere when you can, e.g.:

```
kwlist = [u'ελληνικού', u'Σμύρνη', u'Αδαμάντιος', u'Korais']
```

Comment: It comes for a query using sqlalchemy. The kwlist is dynamic too.

Comment: If i use unicode in the kwlist it throws an UnicodeEncodeError.